# Sorting nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I have to sort a nested dictionary which looks like this:

```
{'Red': {'A': 1000, 'B': 2000},
'Blue': {'C': 4000, 'D':3000, 'E':1000, 'Y': 2000},
'Yellow': {'F':5000, 'G':6000, 'J': 3000}}
```

And I need to sort it first by the integer values(descending),and then by how many keys there are in the **nested** dictionary(also descending) ,so the printed version looks like this:

```
 Yellow - G - 6000
 Yellow - F - 5000
 Yellow - J 3000
 Blue - C - 4000
 Blue - D - 3000
 Blue - Y - 2000
 Blue - E - 1000
 Red - B - 2000
 Red A - 1000
```

Comment: If you sort by the number of keys, shouldn't there be `Blue` (4 keys) before `Yellow` (3 keys) in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'Red': {'A': 1000, 'B': 2000}, 'Blue': {'C': 4000, 'D':3000, 'E':1000, 'Y': 2000},
     'Yellow': {'F':5000, 'G':6000, 'J': 3000}}

flat_list = []
for k1, v1 in d.items():
        l = len(v1.keys())
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            flat_list.append((v2, l, k1, k2))
flat_list.sort(reverse=True)

for (v2, l, k1, k2) in flat_list:
    print('{} - {} - {}'.format(k1, k2, v2))
```

will print:

```
Yellow - G - 6000
Yellow - F - 5000
Blue - C - 4000
Blue - D - 3000
Yellow - J - 3000
Blue - Y - 2000
Red - B - 2000
Blue - E - 1000
Red - A - 1000
```

As @gred stated in the comment your expected answer does not meet your sorting description as Blue wins Yellow on 4000 and tie at 3000